# Android Studio can't get the right sql query

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have an application in Android studio and i fetch some data from an external database.So i wanted to fetch specific data in some cases and i used in my databaseHelper an if statement that actually doesn't work for me.You can see the if statement in **public List getListMbs()**.When i open the app it actually just fetch everything from the table so the if doesn't work.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
public static final String DBNAME = "mydb.sqlite";
public static final String DBLOCATION = "/data/data/com.hfad.myapp/databases/";
private Context mContext;
private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DBNAME, null, 1);
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public void openDatabase() {
    String dbPath = mContext.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).getPath();
    if(mDatabase != null && mDatabase.isOpen()) {
        return;
    }
    mDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

public void closeDatabase() {
    if(mDatabase!=null) {
        mDatabase.close();
    }
}

public List<Cases> getListCases() {
    Cases caze= null;
    List<Cases> casesList = new ArrayList<>();
    openDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Cases", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        caze = new Cases(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), ListCases.pose);
        casesList.add(caze);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    closeDatabase();
    return casesList;
}

public List<Motherboards> getListMbs() {
    Motherboards mbs = null;
    List<Motherboards> mbsList = new ArrayList<>();
    openDatabase();
    String query = ("SELECT * FROM Motherboards");
    if(ListCases.mboardsize == "mATX"){
        query="SELECT * FROM Motherboards WHERE Size ='mATX'";
    }
    if(ListCases.mboardsize == "ATX")
    {
        query="SELECT * FROM Motherboards WHERE Size ='ATX'";
    }
    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        mbs = new Motherboards(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), mainmenu.motherboard_btn_state);
        mbsList.add(mbs);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    closeDatabase();
    return mbsList;
}


}
```

Comment: That's not how you compare strings in java. Google it.

Comment: @323go oh my god!! thank you so much!!!!! :P i found it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrong compare

```
==
```

->

```
.equals("string");
```